# In XML Schema is it possible to represent an element in two different ways? (based on the value of an attribute)

Tags: xml

So for example the rule I want is if my XML element attribute is mode 'Date'
Then the element will have sub elements called Dateformat

```
IF mode is Date use this format

<Element1 Mode="Date">
   <Format value="yyyymmdd" UTC="false"/>
</Element1>

ELSE use this format

<Element1 Mode="AllOtherMode" setting1="" setting2="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in XSD 1.1 using "conditional type assignment" where the type of an element is a function of the values of its attributes.

It's not possible in XSD 1.0.